# PHP include() Issue

Tags: php, include

I am trying to do some simple form validation making sure that whatever is entered does not exceed a certain character limit, but can't seem to get it to work. When I attempt to run this code:

```
$str = "?id=";
$id = $_POST['ID'];

if (strlen($_POST['fname']) > 1) {
    $message = "Character cannot be more than...";
    include 'edit.php' . $str . $id;
    exit();
}
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: include(edit.php?id=97) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/update.php on line 15

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'edit.php?id=97' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/update.php on line 15
```

From what I've been reading, it is actually looking for the file `edit.php?id=97` as opposed to looking for `edit.php` and appending the id. I have no idea what to do. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the values for `$str` and `$id`?

Comment: why you won't read [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) before you ask question? `Example #3 include() through HTTP`

Comment: I've read that, didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

An include file is just a file, it is not a HTTP request, therefore a GET param does make not sense in that context. You could access `$id` and `$str` in that include if you need to.

You *can* include via HTTP (start the string with a valid protocol) if your `php.ini` has it enabled ([`allow_url_include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include), disabled by default), but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't `include` a local file with HTTP query parameters.

At a guess, I'd say you want to do a header redirect

```
header(sprintf('Location: http://your-domain.com/edit.php?id=%d', $id));
exit;
```

That aside, I find it much easier to follow this workflow when dealing with forms:

1. GET form page. Form action is the same page
2. POST form data. Detect POST method and validate results
3. If valid, redirect to success page. If not, re-display form with notifications / flags

Comment: He'd have to pass `$message` along too if he were to do it that way. Also, this may be of use: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: @Mark Could use a flash-messenger pattern (one-time session message) but as mentioned, I prefer to handle the form processing in the same file and simply re-display if not valid which would make `$message` available.

Comment: The only problem with loading back the page if not valid is the *"Are you sure you want to resent POST data"* dialog that can be confusing to some users if they end up on it by refresh/back/forward/etc.

Comment: @alex I don't reload the page if not valid, it's all part of the POST request.

Comment: @Phil: Yeah, but I mean your end users may.

Comment: @alex: I think he means he posts the form back to the same page if it's invalid, and redirects away if it is valid. If your users press "refresh" while they're in the middle of filling out a form, it's their own dumb fault.

Comment: @Mark Yeah, I knew what he meant, was just throwing in my 2c :)

Answer (score 1):

You cant include a file the way you're trying. Try removing the `?id=x` part and it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanna do it that way...

```
if (strlen($_POST['fname']) > 1) {
    $message = "Character cannot be more than...";
    echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/edit.php'.$str.$id.'&message='.$message);
    exit();
}
```

but try it like this...

```
if (strlen($_POST['fname']) > 1) {
    $message = "Character cannot be more than...";
    include_once 'edit.php';
    exit();
}
```

or tell us what really you want to do...

Comment: Didn't work. I need it to go back to a page displaying the content that the id holds. The first one called it, but would not display the error message ($message).

Answer (score 0):

In your including file:

```
include('edit.php');
```

Inside of edit.php:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Variable is already passed (actually code from edit.php is passed to parent script), no need to do that.

Comment: Figured it would make edit.php a bit more reusable instead of id variable being set by including script.